# Visual Studio 2010 Post Deploy command line copy

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I know you can have post build command line events... executing a batch file, etc.  What I can't find is any information about whether or not there is a post DEPLOY version of this.

I build my solution all the time, but I only deploy once in a while.  There are certain things I do manually, which I would prefer to do automatically via a batch file after a successful deploy.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx#1

Sadly, there are issues with this solution which I posted in a separate thread which I can not seem to locate at the moment... *facepalm*

> Tasks provide the code that runs during the build process. Tasks are contained in targets. A library of typical tasks is included with MSBuild, and you can also create your own tasks. For more information about the library of tasks that are included with MSBuild, see Task reference.
>
> Tasks
> Examples of tasks include Copy, which copies one or more files, MakeDir, which creates a directory, and Csc, which compiles Visual C# source code files. Each task is implemented as a .NET class that implements the ITask interface, which is defined in the Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll assembly.
>
> There are two approaches you can use when implementing a task:
>
> Implement the ITask interface directly.
>
> Derive your class from the helper class, Task, which is defined in the Microsoft.Build.Utilities.dll assembly. Task implements ITask and provides default implementations of some ITask members. Additionally, logging is easier.
>
> In both cases, you must add to your class a method named Execute, which is the method that is called when the task runs. This method takes no parameters and returns a Boolean value: true if the task succeeded or false if it failed. The following example shows a task that performs no action and returns true.

Comment: If the link dies so does your answer

Comment: care to explain that comment? The link is active.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, put useful info in your answer

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that concept, but I added some copied text.

Comment: You must never have found a question for some obscure problem with only one answer that points to a dead link. I have, it's very  frustrating

Comment: HA!  Yes, I have.  However, in my opinion, dead link answers are dead questions on purpose because whatever drove the question is likely no good either, so I keep looking for a newer question.  I doubt the answer to "How do you balance a person's humors" with references to leeching someone is very valuable anymore.

Comment: Agreed, but I've worked at places that use ancient technology so there might not be a newer question.

Answer (score 1):

**There may be a better way to do this, and I know the following method is less than ideal**

For the rare cases you deploy, you could just write an external msbuild script that builds your project, deploys the code, and then run yours batch script.

Using the MSBuild Task to build another MSBuild project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx

Using MSDeploy as Build Task:

http://www.compsoft.co.uk/Blog/2009/12/using-msdeploy-as-build-task-in-tfs.html

Invoking batch files from MSBuild:

http://www.danielfortunov.com/software/$daniel_fortunovs_adventures_in_software_development/2009/05/21/invoking_batch_files_from_msbuild

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I read a LOT since posting that question and found this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx#1 which led to another question on a different forum...